# Active Directory C# Cannot Set Extension Attribute when deployed

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am attempting to programatically set attributes in Active Directory. It works when running locally, however, when i run it deployed on our IIS server, it fails silently.

My code for this is as follows:

```
try
{
      using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, null, _DomainDN))
      {
           DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=-----,DC=-----,DC=-----");
           DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
           search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName=";
           search.Filter = search.Filter + upn + "))";
           search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

           SearchResultCollection rs = search.FindAll();

           foreach (SearchResult r in rs)
           {
               DirectoryEntry entryToUpdate = r.GetDirectoryEntry();
               entryToUpdate.Properties["extensionAttribute1"].Value = "1";
               entryToUpdate.CommitChanges();
           }
      }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //.....FAILS SILENTLY. NO ERROR THROWN
}
```

If anyone has a resolution to this i would be very grateful.

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you checked if the PrincipalContext has inner exception or extended exceptions if you set a breakpoint in Visual Studio just after the declaring of the context?

Comment: Seems like permission issue. Can you try different PrincipalContext initialization with different authorization?

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari I cant set a break point in visual studio as it only happens when deployed and not locally like i mentioned

Comment: @VitaliyK surely the authorisation is the same whether its locally or IIS. It works locally so i dont understand how there would be a permission issue however, i dont have any other authorisation to use

Comment: You can attach Visual Studio to the IIS process. You might want to google a bit and read up on it, that will give you a possibility to debug after deployment to IIS. On another note, my first guess would be that the user account that is using the application pool in IIS doesn´t have the proper write-rights in you AD while the user account that you use in visual studio does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure all the Active Directory Services are installed via Server Manager on the machine that is hosting IIS? They need to be running for LDAP queries to work.
thanks